Recursively Access Element Values in a Nested Dictionary
looking for a more robust method to access an element in a nested dictionary using MainKey (which can be at any depth), SubKey (always immediately following MainKey), and Element (following SubKey at any depth). While my current implementation works for contiguous MainKey, SubKey, and Element, it struggles when they're not directly adjacent. Any suggestions on how to improve this?
Nested_Dict =
{'candela_samples_generic': {'drc_dtcs': {'domain_name': 'TEMPLATE-DOMAIN', 'dtc_all': {'0x930001': {'identification': {'udsDtcValue': '0x9300', 'fault_type': '0x11', 'description': 'GNSS antenna short to ground'}, 'snapshots': {'snapshot_record_content': 'base', 'snapshot_records_numbers': ['0x01']}, 'functional_conditions': {'failure_name': 'short_to_ground', 'mnemonic': 'DTC_GNSS_Antenna_Short_to_ground'}}}}}}`

Working for result = get_value_nested_dict(nested_dict, 'dtc_all', '0x930001', 'identification') not for result = get_value_nested_dict(nested_dict, 'dtc_all', '0x930001', 'udsDtcValue') 

def get_value_nested_dict(nested_dict, main_key, sub_key, element):
    # Initialize a list to store the results
    results = []

    # Recursive function to search for the element in nested dictionaries
    def search_nested_dict(nested_dict, main_key, sub_key, element):
        # Iterate over the dictionary items
        for key, value in nested_dict.items():
            # Check if the current key matches the main key
            if key == main_key:
                # Check if the sub_key exists in the value
                if sub_key in value:
                    # Check if the element exists directly under the sub_key
                    if element in value[sub_key]:
                        results.append(value[sub_key][element])
                    # If not, recursively search for the element in the sub-dictionary
                    elif isinstance(value[sub_key], dict):
                        search_nested_dict(value[sub_key], main_key, sub_key, element)
            # If the value is a dictionary, recursively call the function
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                search_nested_dict(value, main_key, sub_key, element)

    # Start the recursive search
    search_nested_dict(nested_dict, main_key, sub_key, element)

    return results


To optimize the function you should adjust your strategy:

Search through the dictionary to find MainKey.
Once MainKey is found, right away look for SubKey within the part of the dictionary where MainKey was found.
After findingSubKey, we search everything under SubKey to find Element.

The optimized version:
def get_value_nested_dict(nested_dict, main_key, sub_key, element):
    results = []
    def search_for_element(sub_dict, looking_for_element):
        if isinstance(sub_dict, dict):
            for k, v in sub_dict.items():
                if k == element and looking_for_element:
                    results.append(v)
                else:
                    search_for_element(v, looking_for_element)
    def search_nested_dict(current_dict):
        if isinstance(current_dict, dict):
            for key, value in current_dict.items():
                if key == main_key:
                    if sub_key in value:
                        search_for_element(value[sub_key], True)
                    else:
                        search_for_element(value, False)
                else:
                    search_nested_dict(value)
    search_nested_dict(nested_dict)
    return results


Could you please support if you can on this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78279835/aggregating-inputs-into-a-consolidated-dictionary         Thanks in advance!

You can flatten dict using following code.
import collections
from itertools import chain 

def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='$'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(items)
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for idx, value in enumerate(v):
                items.extend(flatten(value, new_key + sep + str(idx), sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

Nested_Dict = {'candela_samples_generic': {'drc_dtcs': {'domain_name': 'TEMPLATE-DOMAIN', 'dtc_all': {'0x930001': {'identification': {'udsDtcValue': '0x9300', 'fault_type': '0x11', 'description': 'GNSS antenna short to ground'}, 'snapshots': {'snapshot_record_content': 'base', 'snapshot_records_numbers': ['0x01']}, 'functional_conditions': {'failure_name': 'short_to_ground', 'mnemonic': 'DTC_GNSS_Antenna_Short_to_ground'}}}}}}

print(flatten(Nested_Dict))

After this, you can traverse on flatten dict keys & check you conditions
