Aggregating Inputs into a Consolidated Dictionary
Nested_Dict =
{'candela_samples_generic': {'drc_dtcs': {'domain_name': 'TEMPLATE-DOMAIN', 'dtc_all':{ 
'0x930001': {'identification': {'udsDtcValue': '0x9300', 'FaultType': '0x11', 'description': 'GNSS antenna short to ground'}, 
'functional_conditions': {'failure_name': 'short_to_ground', 'mnemonic': 'DTC_GNSS_Antenna_Short_to_ground'}},
'0x212021': {'identification': {'udsDtcValue': '0x2120', 'FaultType': '0x21', 'description': 'ECU internal Failure'},
'functional_conditions': {'failure_name': 'short_to_ground', 'mnemonic': 'DTC_GNSS_Antenna_Short_to_ground'}}}}}}

Header = {
    'dtc_all': {
        'DiagnosticTroubleCodeUds': {'udsDtcValue': None, 'FaultType': None},
        'dtcProps': {'description': None},
        'DiagnosticTroubleCodeObd': {'failure_name': None}   
    }
}

SubkeyList = ['0x930001','0x240001']

Take an element from the SubkeyList and one header keys at a time from the dictionary (there can be multiple header keys like dtc_all).
Iterate inside the header dictionary over the values of the dictionary, such as 'udsDtcValue'.
For example:
    Main_Key = dtc_all
    Sub_Key = 0x212021
    Element = udsDtcValue

Pass these parameters to the function get_value_nested_dict(nested_dict, Main_Key, Sub_Key, Element). This function will return the element value.
get_value_nested_dict func which is working as expected for Element value retriaval I've posted for the reference.
At the same time, create a new dictionary and update the element value at the right place, such as 'udsDtcValue': '0x9300'.
Also, ensure that the sequence of keys remains the same as in the header.
Similarly, iterate inside the header dictionary over all the values of the dictionary, such as FaultType, description, until failure_name.
Repeat these iterations for each element in the SubkeyList and append the results in the new_dict in the same sequence.
Any suggestions on how to proceed?
Output: New_Dict should look like this:
New_Dict= 
{'dtc_all': 
{'0x930001': {'DiagnosticTroubleCodeUds': {'udsDtcValue': '0x9300', 'FaultType': '0x11'}, 'dtcProps':{'description': 'GNSS antenna short to ground'}, 'DiagnosticTroubleCodeObd': {'failure_name':short_to_ground}}},
{'0x212021': {'DiagnosticTroubleCodeUds': {'udsDtcValue': '0x2120', 'FaultType': '0x21'}, 'dtcProps':{'description': 'ECU internal Failure'}, 'DiagnosticTroubleCodeObd': {'failure_name':short_to_ground}}}}


def get_value_nested_dict(nested_dict, main_key, sub_key, element):
    results = []
    def search_for_element(sub_dict, looking_for_element):
        if isinstance(sub_dict, dict):
            for k, v in sub_dict.items():
                if k == element and looking_for_element:
                    results.append(v)
                else:
                    search_for_element(v, looking_for_element)
    def search_nested_dict(current_dict):
        if isinstance(current_dict, dict):
            for key, value in current_dict.items():
                if key == main_key:
                    if sub_key in value:
                        search_for_element(value[sub_key], True)
                    else:
                        search_for_element(value, False)
                else:
                    search_nested_dict(value)
    search_nested_dict(nested_dict)
    return results



Initialize an empty dictionary new_dict

Iterate over the SubkeyList

For each sub_key in SubkeyList create a new dictionary: sub_dict

For each element in the Header['dtc_all'] get the value from the Nested_Dict using get_value_nested_dict and add it to sub_dict

Add sub_dict to new_dict under sub_key
def create_new_dict(Nested_Dict, Header, SubkeyList):
    new_dict = {}
    for sub_key in SubkeyList:
        sub_dict = {}
        for element, value in Header['dtc_all'].items():
            value = get_value_nested_dict(Nested_Dict, 'dtc_all', sub_key, element)
            if value:
                sub_dict[element] = value[0]
        new_dict[sub_key] = sub_dict
    return new_dict

New_dict = create_new_dict(Nested_Dict, Header, SubkeyList)



Getting empty dict: {'0x930001': {}, '0x212021': {}}  The element value we are getting are DiagnosticTroubleCodeUds
dtcProps
DiagnosticTroubleCodeObd not the values of these dictionaries we need to iterate over values udsDtcValue etc not over keys.

Could you please better explain your problem as a question? Write it down as a question and @tag me

Could you please try printing element in second for loop in your code there you will get DiagnosticTroubleCodeUds dtcProps DiagnosticTroubleCodeObd values from header dict not as we wanted udsDtcValue etc. @László Hunyadi I will tag in my next question for sure very soon : )

I've modified the solution to hopefully match your needs but I can't write an answer as a comment due to it lacking the proper formatting tools. Could you please write down a detailed question?

Here is the new question:  @László Hunyadi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78284077/iterate-over-values-of-nested-dictionary

If it works, could you please upvote and mark the answer as correct?
I'd really appreciate it. It helps me out a lot
